# Activity Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT not working as expected

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created four activities all of which  are opened with the flag `REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

- I opened activities A, B, C and D in this order
- Now stack is A -> B -> C -> D
- Now I opened activity A again, stack being B -> C -> D -> A
- When I click back, the app minimises rather than going to D.

Please help me on this.

Please find my four Activites below
**MainACtivity:**

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity

{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var textView = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        textView.Text = "A";
        textView.Click += TextView_Click;

    }

    private void TextView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityB));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
        this.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**ACtivityB:**

```
 public class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity

{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var textView = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        textView.Text = "B";
        textView.Click += TextView_Click;
    }

    private void TextView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityC));
        intent.SetFlags( ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
        this.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**ActivityC**:

```
 public class ActivityC : AppCompatActivity

{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var textView = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        textView.Text = "C";
        textView.Click += TextView_Click;
    }

    private void TextView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityD));
        intent.SetFlags( ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
        this.StartActivity(intent);
    }     
}
```

**ActivityD:**

```
 public class ActivityD : AppCompatActivity

{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var textView = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        textView.Text = "D";
        textView.Click += TextView_Click;
    }

    private void TextView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.SetFlags( ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
        this.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have create four activities ? I do not see any Activity.

Comment: @ramanji boyapati  post relevant code

Comment: @ADM I have added my activites, please check. Thank you.

Comment: @Gowthaman M I have added my activites, please check. Thank you.

Comment: @ramanjiboyapati  intent.SetFlags( ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront); remove this line check it let me know...by default categories launch mode is standard..

Comment: @GowthamanM If i remove ReOrderToFront Activity will be recreating and Stack will be A->B->C->D->A. But i need the Stack is B->C->D->A

Comment: OK i understand..i given you reference please learn about that..you can fined the solution

Answer (score 0):

**There are four launch modes for activity. They are:**

1. standard
2. singleTop
3. singleTask
4. singleInstance

> **More reference :**https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242

Learn about launch modes,then you can achieve.

Comment: I have tried with Launch modes. I have used single instance. This one is working fine. But if I use the single instance Launch mode in SAMSUNG Galaxy s5 phone, opening multiple instances of app.